Why is my animated object "shooting" around?
I am trying to animate a cloth simulation. I want to pull the cloth along the floor and drag it up to the ceiling and in between it will interact with some objects.
Two issues occur when I try to achieve this:

I have deleted all the keyframes but the cloth is still simulating? Can I delete the animation data somewhere so I can start animating from scratch?
I have two Hook Empties attached to two vertices and I wanted to parent these to another object to move the cloth around and drag it to the ceiling. However, when I add Location Keyframes to move it around, the cloth just "shoots" around. There is no smooth transition.



Here is the blend file:


It looks like a Cache problem, not sure what's happening, but change a parameter (like the Quality Steps) and play again and it seems to work this time

Ah okay. What about the object that "shoots" around? I updated the blender file.

again I had to change a parameter so that it calculates again and it works

I did change a parameter. The initial problem was solved, but now when I added back in the Empty to drag the cloth around, I still have the issue of the object behaving weird instead of following along the empty. That's why I changed the file.

I'm talking about your new file, it works fine if it recalculates, not sure what happens if it doesn't for you...
